# Passing concatenated string to javascript to import command

Tags: javascript

I have the following at the top of my JS code (it's vanilla JS, no libs used)

```
var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
l = unescape(temp[1]);
temp = parameters[1].split("=");
p = unescape(temp[1]);
document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = l;


var imsrc = '../js/' + l + '.js';

import sources from imsrc;
```

The issue is that I am trying to pass the imsrc parameter in to the import and I'm getting an error (`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing module specifier after 'from' keyword`) returned in the webtools

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Sorry, newbie question.

Comment: You can't use the normal import with dynamic names, you will have to use the function version..  `const sources = await import(imsrc)`

Comment: If you're interested, the spec says module specifier must be a _string literal_. Keith's suggestion is the solution. [Reference](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#prod-ModuleSpecifier)

Comment: @Keith - I've changed the code to `const imsrc = "../js/images.js";` followed by the `const sources = await import(imsrc)` as suggested above. When I use the inspector though, `sources` is undefined. the old line `import sources from imsrc;` worked fine. Am I missing something?